# replace efi firmware with old legacy bios?

Tags: bios, uefi, mbr, gpt, efi

So I bought a new laptop with 64-bit windows 8 pre-installed, and in preparation for downgrading to win7 32-bit, i've been reading about EFI and MBR etc.. It seems like the firmware which boots disks on my pc is EFI. I think already know how to install windows 7 now (by converting gpt to mbr), but firstly, will it even boot if I set boot mode to csm? (The installation dvd seems to work so my guess is yes)

And now my main question is this: Is it possible to flash my firmware to a legacy bios-based one instead of efi?

Comment: **Is it possible to flash my firmware to a legacy bios-based one instead of efi?** - No; this isn't possible.  Its also not required Windows 7 supports UEFI/GPT.  Its not clear the reason you want to enable legacy support and use MBR partitions when Windows 7 has not problem with GPT partitions.

Comment: My win7 installation says it cannot be installed on this disk because it's gpt. Also, please ignore the reason for now.

Comment: You need to boot your installation disk while in EFI mode.  Please update your question to provide the reason, its important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UEFI is perfectly capable of booting BIOS-bootable operating systems, using the so called “Compatibility Support Module” (CSM), which emulates all the necessary stuff.

And no, you cannot simply flash whatever you like. The firmware/BIOS is created specifically for your device. Unless the manufacturer provides a legacy BIOS firmware (he won’t), you’re stuck with UEFI/CSM.

Windows is too dumb to BIOS-boot from GPT disks. So just fire up the command prompt with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> (possible at any time in Windows Setup) and launch `diskpart`. Then:

- Find your disk’s number with `list disk`
- Select the correct disk with `select disk 9`, where `9` is your disk’s number.
- Wipe it using `clean` **WARNING:** This will remove all partitions on the selected disk instantly and without asking for confirmation!

After that, continue with the setup routine.

Comment: Thanks! could help me with this related question as well? http://superuser.com/questions/867294/installing-32-bit-windows-diskpart-convert-mbr-error

Answer (score 1):

Daniel B's answer is correct, but I want to note a few points:

- ***IN THEORY,*** you could flash an old-style BIOS over an EFI. The trouble is that you'd need to develop this BIOS yourself. If you're into this sort of thing, you could look at [CoreBoot](http://www.coreboot.org/) with an open-source BIOS payload. This is way too much hassle for most people, though. I recommend it only if you're into tinkering at this level, with bonus motivation if your EFI implementation is *really* bad.
- Although *most* UEFIs provide a CSM, a few don't. I own a couple of machines that lack this feature (both with 32-bit EFIs). I fully expect this feature to start disappearing in the not-too-distant future.
- A 32-bit OS is difficult or impossible to boot (in EFI mode) on a 64-bit EFI, so if booting a 32-bit version of Windows is really a requirement, the need for a BIOS-mode boot is necessary for minusatwelfth's situation. OTOH, using a 32-bit OS on 64-bit hardware is not something I'd recommend in most situations, so I recommend reviewing that detail.
- Windows 7 is perfectly capable of installing in EFI mode. There are some issues with getting a standard installation disc to boot that way, but they can be overcome. (I don't have any URLs handy, but I'm sure a web search will turn them up.) Thus, doing a 64-bit EFI-mode installation of Windows 7 would probably work as well as a 32-bit BIOS mode installation, assuming the 32-bit part isn't necessary for some reason.