# installing 32-bit windows: diskpart convert mbr error

Tags: windows, mbr, gpt, efi, diskpart

I have an efi-based 64 bit system with win 8 pre-installed. I want to downgrade to 32-bit win 7 and so I booted up a bootable win 7 usb and opened command-prompt with shift+f10. I used convert mbr command on disk 0 (which should be gpt) and it says: "the specified disk is not convertible. cdroms and dvds are examples of disks that are not convertible"

Now, I have not cleaned the disk yet, so this might explain the error. However, I would think a different error message would appear if that were the case and I don't want a laptop without an os. Furthermore, I cannot enter "Repair your computer"  as it said system recovery options was incompatible. What is going on here? i definitely want to convert to mbr for other reasons too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove all partitions. This a limitation of Windows’ disk management.

After that, you can use `convert mbr`. But since you have to remove all partitions anyway, `clean` is much faster and removes the partitioning scheme, too.

And yes, this is the exact error message you’ll get on a non-empty disk:

```
DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Reserved            32 MB    17 KB
  Partition 2    Primary           2014 MB    32 MB

DISKPART> convert mbr

Virtual Disk Service error:
The specified disk is not convertible. CDROMs and DVDs
are examples of disks that are not convertable.
```

On the other hand, if the disk is empty:

```
DISKPART> list partition

There are no partitions on this disk to show.

DISKPART> convert mbr

DiskPart successfully converted the selected disk to MBR format.
```